# How can I use sbt 0.12 and 0.13 together?

Tags: sbt

I have a bunch of projects that use SBT 0.13, but I'm presently running SBT 0.12, with global plugins specific to it. Is there any way I can have both versions on my machine?

Comment: is the question how to define different global plugins for different sbt versions?

Comment: @MarkHarrah Maybe. I do have global plugins in use, and they are not compatible with 0.13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, there are these points to consider:

1. The launcher version used.  sbt 0.13 launchers should support building with sbt 0.12, but 0.12 launchers cannot build with sbt 0.13 because of a JLine change.
2. Global plugins.  Global plugins for sbt 0.13 should go in `~/.sbt/0.13/` by default.  For compatibility, 0.13 has to read from plain `~/.sbt/` as well, however.  A solution is to change the 0.12 startup script to look in `~/.sbt/0.12/`.  For example:

   java ... -Dsbt.global.base=/home/user/.sbt/0.12/ ...
3. sbt 0.13 fixes several Ivy cache issues, but it cannot always detect corruption due to sbt 0.12.